# Polymer 1.x: Deleting an item from iron-list

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I am trying to delete an item from `iron-list` using the following code.

my-element.html

```
<iron-list id="list" items="[[items]]" as="item"
           selected-items="{{selectedItems}}"
           selection-enabled multi-selection>
  <template>
    <my-item item="[[item]]" on-tap="_onItemTap"></my-item>
  </template>
</iron-list>
...
_onItemTap: function(e) {
  this.items.splice(e.model.index, 1);
}
```

#### Expected behavior

1. Tap list item
2. List item disappears
3. Select next list item
4. Next list item is selected

#### Actual behavior

1. Tap list item
2. List item *does not* disappear
3. Select *same* list item (i.e., the one previously intended to be deleted)
4. *Next* list item is actually selected (i.e., index offset by one)

#### Questions

- What code will result in the desired / expected behavior?
- Please provide a working jsBin sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[See this answer for specific syntax contributing to the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34635363/1640892).

[Here is a working JSBin](http://jsbin.com/nuwocogogo/1/edit?html,console,output).

http://jsbin.com/qefemoloxi/1/edit?html,console,output

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <base href="https://polygit.org/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">
  <link href="paper-button/paper-button.html" rel="import">
  <link href="iron-list/iron-list.html" rel="import">
</head>
<body>

<dom-module id="x-element">

<template>
  <style>
    iron-list {
      height: 100vh;
    }
  </style>
  <iron-list id="list" items="[[items]]" as="item">
    <template>
      <paper-button on-tap="_deleteItem">[[item.name]]</paper-button>
    </template>
  </iron-list>
</template>

<script>
  (function(){
    Polymer({
      is: "x-element",
      properties: {
        items: {
          type: Array,
          value: function() {
            return [
              { 'name':'foo' },
              { 'name':'bar' },
              { 'name':'qux' },
              { 'name':'baz' },
              { 'name':'quux'}
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      _deleteItem: function(e) {
        console.log(e.model.index);
        this.splice('items', e.model.index, 1);
        this.$.list.fire('resize');
      }
    });
  })();
</script>

</dom-module>

<x-element></x-element>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

[A summary of this page](https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-list/issues/111) suggests [this documentation as follows](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties.html#array-observation):

Question

```
app.removeItem = function(index) {
  app.data.splice(index, 1);
  console.log("Removing " + index);
  document.querySelector('#tobuy').fire('resize');
};
```

Reply

> `document.querySelector('#tobuy').push('items', {name: "Foo"})`
>
> then you don't need to call resize.
>
> ref: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties.html#array-observation

Answer (score 0):

[This documentation on array mutation provides the following boilerplate code](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties.html#array-mutation):

custom-element.html

```
<dom-module id="custom-element">
  <template>
    <template is="dom-repeat"></template>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'custom-element',
      addUser: function(user) {
        this.push('users', user);
      },
      removeUser: function(user) {
        var index = this.users.indexOf(user);
        this.splice('users', index, 1);
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Applying that to this case:

my-element.html

```
// As a syntactical matter, replace the following line
// this.items.splice(e.model.index, 1);
// With this line
this.splice('items', e.model.index, 1);
this.$.list.fire('resize');
```

A problem with this solution, however, is that it deletes the last item from the `iron-list`, not the item at the expected index. In other words, it behaves like one would expect `this.items.pop()`.

It also throws the following curious error message:

console.log

```
Uncaught TypeError: <item> should be a valid item
```

Answer (score 0):

[See this answer for full code solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34634962/1640892).

The problem here was caused by the fact that my `item.html` file was setting and displaying properties outside the `item.` property. So, when the `iron-list.(this.)splice('items', e.model.index, 1);` array mutation method was called, the non `item` properties were not being removed from the DOM.

Example:

my-list-item.html

```
this.set(     'name', this.item.foo.bar.qux); // This syntax caused the problem
this.set('item.name', this.item.foo.bar.qux); // This fixed the problem
```

my-iron-list.html

```
this.splice('items', e.model.index, 1);
```