# Removing an item from iron-list with splice updates array correctly but not display

Tags: arrays, polymer, splice

I have a custom element that incorporates an iron-list.  Each list item formats and displays an object and each item has a clickable `<div>` that is used to delete that item.  The list is displaying correctly.  I am receiving the click event in my 'on-click' method.  The 'on-click' method uses splice to remove the item.  As can be seen in my code, I log the listData property (my items) before and after the splice.  listData is updated correctly when I remove any item.  However, the removed item remains displayed and the item at the end of the list is actually removed from the display rather than the desired one.  I have tried a few things I have seen (not much), including some stuff from Polymer docs, with no luck.  Can someone please help?  Here is the element, minus a lot of the 'fluff'.

```
 <dom-module id="cnid-list">

  <template>

    <style include="cnid-list-style"></style>


    <iron-list id="callerList" items="[[listData]]" as="item">
      <template>
        <div class="recents-list">
        <div id="{{index2id(item.index)}}" on-click="onClickedItem"></div>
        </div>
      </template>
    </iron-list>

  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
        is: 'cnid-list',
        properties: {
          carrier: String,
          listData: { type: Array, 
                      value: function() { return []; }
                    }
        },

         ready: function() {
           console.log('cnid-list ready');
           myArray = getMyArray(); // returns an array of objects
           this.listData=myArray;

           for(var i = 0; i < this.listData.length; i++) {
               this.listData[i].index = i;
             }
         },

         index2id: function(index) {
             return "_" + index;
         },

         id2index: function(id) {
           return Number(id.substr(1));
         },

         onClickedItem: function(e) {
           for(var i = 0; i < this.listData.length; i++) {
             console.log('on-click list item before: ', this.listData[i]);
           }

           idx = this.id2index(e.target.getAttribute('id'));
           console.log('index is ' + idx);

           Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector('#callerList').splice('items', idx, 1);
           for(var i = 0; i < this.listData.length; i++) {
             console.log('on-click list item after: ', this.listData[i]);
           }
        }
    });
  </script>
 </dom-module>
```

Comment: Why do you `.splice()` on `Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector('#callerList').splice('items', idx, 1)` instead of `this.list.data`? You should use https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties.html#array-mutation instead of `splice()`

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting question and Günter's comment points you in the right direction. You actually are using the array mutation method's the he links to. But you are using them on `iron-list` rather than on you own custom element `cnid-list`. The `items` property in `iron-list` does not notify changes to host elements. So even though it may have changed internally, it does not propagate the change to `cnid-list`. Furthermore, you are using [one-way data-bindings](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#property-binding) (the square brackets in `items="[[listData]]"`) which also does not communicate the changes from child to host.

The solution is quite simple, call splice on `cnid-list`

```
this.splice('listData', idx, 1);
```

Note that in your `ready` function, you should also use the Polymer API to set the index.

Comment: Thanks, I actually had tried that but kept getting errors that 'splice' was not a method of 'undefined' (or something of that nature).

Comment: I tried to simplify my code snippet, so I do not show a bunch of the stuff in the template.  In the template, there is a lot of stuff in curly braces '{{}}' which invoke a function to compute the data to be displayed from the data in items[index].  I have since changed my items array to an array of objects with the actual display data (no computation in the element) and it now works!  I went back and implemented this element (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34627793/polymer-1-x-deleting-an-item-from-iron-list) as-is, which worked, and then worked backwards from there to figure out my issue.

Comment: If you call `this.splice` inside `onClickedItem` instead of the `Polymer.dom...` that you have now, you should get no such errors. The error sounds like a issue of scope. Did you maybe try to call `this.splice` in some callback, like a `forEach` or something like that?