# Polymer - How to remove an item from iron-list?

Tags: polymer, iron-list

This live snippet builds a web-component which uses `iron-list`. Each item in the list has a delete button which, on click, removes the item from the list.
When an item is removed, all the next items shift up, but the last item displayed stays rather than disapear as it should be.

According to [this stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34627793/polymer-1-x-deleting-an-item-from-iron-list/34634962#34634962), simply by firing the event `resize` on the iron-list should be enough. But in my snippet, this doesn't help. Nether the `iron-resize` or the notifyResize function from the official `iron-list` [documentation](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/iron-list/elements/iron-list).

```html
<script src="https://polygit.org/components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js"></script>

<link rel="import"  href="https://polygit.org/components/polymer/polymer-element.html">
<link rel="import"  href="https://polygit.org/components/iron-list/iron-list.html">
<link rel="import"  href="https://polygit.org/components/paper-button/paper-button.html">

<dom-module id="my-list">
  <template>

    <iron-list id="list" items="{{items}}">
      
      <template>
        <div style="display:flex; justify-content: space-between; align-items: center;">
          
          <div style="margin: 20px; ">
            {{item}}
          </div>
          
          <paper-button on-tap="_onDeleteClicked"
          style="background: red; color: white;">Remove</paper-button>
        </div>
      </template>
      
    </iron-list>
  
  </template>
  
  <script>
    class MyList extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() { return "my-list"; }
      
      // set this element's employees property
      constructor() {
        super();
        this.items = [1,2,3,4]; 
      }
      
      _onDeleteClicked(event){
        this.splice("items", event.model.index, 1);
        
        // ---- any resize call doesn't help a thin ---
  this.$.list.fire('iron-resize');
  this.$.list.fire('resize');
  this.$.list.notifyResize();
      }
    }
  customElements.define(MyList.is, MyList);
  </script>

</dom-module>

<my-list></my-list>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"It's simple! The **css display property of the root element**, in the iron-list's template, **must not be set**. Then just wrap your flexbox in another simple div."

Here's the live snippet solved:

```html
<script src="https://polygit.org/components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js"></script>

<link rel="import"  href="https://polygit.org/components/polymer/polymer-element.html">
<link rel="import"  href="https://polygit.org/components/iron-list/iron-list.html">
<link rel="import"  href="https://polygit.org/components/paper-button/paper-button.html">

<dom-module id="my-list">
  <template>

    <iron-list id="list" items="{{items}}">
      
      <template>
         <!--YOU MUST NO CHANGE THE CSS DISPLAY PROPERTY OF THE ROOT ELEMENT OF THE TEMPLATE!-->
        <div>

         <div style="display:flex; justify-content: space-between; align-items: center;">
          
          <div style="margin: 20px; ">
            {{item}}
          </div>
          
          <paper-button on-tap="_onDeleteClicked"
          style="background: red; color: white;">Remove</paper-button>
         </div>

        </div>
      </template>
      
    </iron-list>
  
  </template>
  
  <script>
    class MyList extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() { return "my-list"; }
      
      // set this element's employees property
      constructor() {
        super();
        this.items = [1,2,3,4]; 
      }
      
      _onDeleteClicked(event){
        this.splice("items", event.model.index, 1);
        this.$.list.notifyResize();
      }
    }
  customElements.define(MyList.is, MyList);
  </script>

</dom-module>

<my-list></my-list>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may find an "hidden" attribute on the last item. As items are reused by iron-list when scrolling the item does not get removed. This CSS rule should hide it away

```
#list [hidden] { display: none; }
```

Comment: Why the hell should I tell iron-list to hide a removed item?!
Furthermore, I solved my problem. It was because I changed the css `display` property of the root element of the template which is in the iron-list.
See the [correct answer and its demo here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47305152/4170935)